# How to control rails resource route options in Ember?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-data

In Rails, I added `[GET] /photos/untagged` route.

It works fine.

```
resources :photos do
  collection do
    get :untagged
  end
end
```

But, I cannot retrieve in Ember.

Ember maybe parse this response as object. Not array. I think it conflict `show` action in Ember.

I don't want to use query params like `/photos?query=untagged`.

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find("photo", "today");
  }
});
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `find` like that, it's for returning single records by id. Instead the simple solution is to override `urlForQuery`:

```
export default Ember.RESTAdapter.extend({
  urlForQuery(query, modelName){
    if(query.untagged){
      delete.query.untagged
      return this._super(query, modelName) + '/untagged';
    }
    return this._super(query, modelName);
  }
});
```

Then to use it:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    return this.store.query("photo", {untagged: true});
  }
});
```